# error C3861: 'cropImage'*: identifier not found

Tags: c++, opencv

While developing a C++ application for face authentication, I encountered 
an error:

```
C3861: 'cropImage'*: identifier not found
```

This the signature of `cropImage`:

```
IplImage* cropImage(IplImage *img,CvRect region);
```

I try to call it in the following function:

```
IplImage *cropFace(IplImage * image, CvPoint eye_left, CvPoint eye_right, double offset_pct[2], CvSize dest_sz)
{//calculate offsets in original image
    ...
    //matrice de rotation
    cv::Mat affine_matrix;
    affine_matrix = cv::getRotationMatrix2D(eye_left, rotation, scale);
    //mtx est la conversion de image IplImage* en matrice mtx
    cv::Mat mtx = cv::Mat(image, true);
    cv::Mat mtx2;
    cv::warpAffine(mtx, mtx2, affine_matrix, mtx.size(), cv::INTER_LINEAR,       cv::BORDER_CONSTANT, cv::Scalar::all(255));
    //mtx est la conversion de matrice mtx2 en image IplImage*
    IplImage image1 = mtx2;
    //crop the rotated image
    double crop_x = eye_left.x - scale * offset_h;
    double crop_y = eye_left.y - scale * offset_v;
    double crop_size0 = dest_sz.width * scale;
    double crop_size1 = dest_sz.height * scale;
    CvRect region;
    region.x = cvFloor(crop_y);
    region.y = cvFloor(crop_y);
    region.width = cvFloor(crop_size0);
    region.height = cvFloor(crop_size1);
    //the problem in this ligne,it seems it has not known cropImage !! :(
    IplImage *image2 = cropImage(&image1, region);
    IplImage *image3 = resizeImage(image2, dest_sz.width, dest_sz.width);
    return image3;
}
```

I think that conversion between IplImage* and Mat has causes this problem.

Comment: Just a tip - if an urgent solution is needed, maybe you should consider paying someone to solve it for you. En plus, la langue officiele ici est anglais, so you should consider posting your error message in English or at least translate/describe it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be were you pointed it out. You are dereferencing it with the `&` symbol even though `image` is already a pointer type, resulting in a double pointer. You should try simply:

```
IplImage *image2 = cropImage(image1, region);
```

Comment: cropImage needs an input parameter whose type IplImage* ... and i have a parameter which is image1  whose parameter is IplImage,that's why i put &image1.
in all cases , i corrected it by writing:

 IplImage image1 =mtx2;// mtx2 whose type cv:Mat
  IplImage* im22=(IplImage*)&image1;

Comment: this problem has been solved the solution is when i write
IplImage *cropFace(IplImage * image, CvPoint eye_left, CvPoint eye_right, double offset_pct[2], CvSize dest_sz)
i corrected by wrinting IplImage * classNoun::cropFace(IplImage * image, CvPoint eye_left, CvPoint eye_right, double offset_pct[2], CvSize dest_sz)
also for another function disatnce i should preceed it by classNoun::
but now i have a new problem 
a first chance Exception  à 0x100e3cf2 dans shervinemami.exe : 0xC0000094: Integer division by zero.